# Excel - Using range for criteria in Sumifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sumifs with 3 pairs of ranges and criterias:

I have one column of data and I want pair of my sumifs range and criteria to be something like:

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, $E$6:$E$2829, "<>"& $F$6:$F$20, range, criteria, etc)
```

I tried to confirm with **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** and to replace the criteria range with a named range and confirm with **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**. Both there solutions will only acount for the first entry in the range ($F$6).

Any way of doing this without a pair of range + criteria for each cell in $F$6:$F$20? Thanks!

Comment: Post sample data then show your output. There may others way to achieve result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as an array formula (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((sum_range)*(range=criteria)*COUNTIF($F$6:$F$20,$E$6:$E$2829))
```

Add more `*(range=criteria)` if needed.